# Is it possible ? - CSS - Parent adapts to child1 while child2 adapts to parent

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am in doubt whether this is conceptually impossible to acheive with css.

I have a parent (red) with two children (green and blue).
Child 1 has a fixed size, and I want the parent to adapt to this.
Child 2 contains a long text, but I want its width to adapt to the parent.

Is it possible in this way to let the parent be controlled / constrained by child 1 while controlling / constraining child 2?

Is this conceptually possible at all?

I need the solution in a react native project, where it behaves exactly as in css, but I formulate my question as a CSS question as I think the problem and solution is related to CSS.

css:

```
.outerContainer {
  background-color: #ff0;
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.elem1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
.elem2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="containerA">
    <div class="elem1A">
      Fixed size elem 1
    </div>
    <div class="elem2A">
          Elem 2 Please keep inside the bounds of the container.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the code pen: https://codepen.io/breakeren/pen/GRBbgaM?editors=1100

[image]

To be clear. What the image shows is NOT what I desire. I desire the blue child to have a width equal to the green child in a way where green child controls parent size and blue child adapts to this resulting size.

Comment: Just to make sure: You want the red container to be _at least_ the same height as the green child, but if the blue child has more content, you want the red container to grow vertically?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Nob. This is what happens and what I want to avoid. I want the blue child to stay within the width of the red parent (which should be the same as the green child). Right now - as on the picture - the red container is adapting to the blue child as well. It should only adapt to the green child and then dictate the resulting width to the blue container. I can of course do this with scripting, but for performance reasons I would like to stick with css.